# why is this for loop stopping half way?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I can't figure out whats wrong here, Im trying to loop through the entire array but its stopping at 'c'.

```
function foo() {
  var temp = ['e', 'm', 'o', 'c', 'l', 'e', 'W'];
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    console.log(temp.pop());
  }
}

foo() // => welc
```

Comment: pop() removes the element from the array... you should use console.log(temp[i])

Comment: Because you are both decreasing the `length` of the array with `.pop()` and increasing `i`  with `i++`. The loop's condition compares `0 < 7`, `1 < 6`, `2 < 5`, `3 < 4`, before stopping at `4 < 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pop()` method removes the last element of  the array, and returns that element and with that changes the length of that array.

And in your loop. you are increasing the `i` and decreasing the array length. so it will go from:

- `0(i) < 7 (array length)`
  to
- `3(i) < 4 (array length)` (here is your `c`)
- and then exit the loop because the `i` will be `4` and the array length will be `3`.

so in your case you can use in the `console.log` the `temp[i]`, to iterate all the array.

```
function foo() {
  var temp = ['e', 'm', 'o', 'c', 'l', 'e', 'W'];
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
     console.log(temp[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does it only the half time, because when you use the `pop()`, it automatically reduces the length. The `for` loop checks the length when every loop is done. Instead use:

```
function foo() {
  var temp = ['e', 'm', 'o', 'c', 'l', 'e', 'W'];
  for (;temp.length > 0;) {
    console.log(temp.pop());
  }
}
```

You won't be needing the counters at all. So we can even switch this to `while` loop.

```
function foo() {
  var temp = ['e', 'm', 'o', 'c', 'l', 'e', 'W'];
  while (temp.length > 0) {
    console.log(temp.pop());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pop temp in the for loop you are changing the length of temp

Answer (score 0):

`pop()` reduces the size of the array. Your code is running like this (L is array length, I is the index).

```
  L I
W 6 0
e 5 1
l 4 2
c 3 3
```

So the loop stops when the index is no longer less than the array length (`i < temp.length`).

Perhaps a change to:

```
for (var i = temp.length; temp.length > 0; i--) {
  console.log(temp.pop());
}
```